# Animating a Border control's width

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to animate a Border control's width in a Windows 8 Metro app. I've managed to animate other properties on the Border, such as Opacity:

```
private void Item_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = sender as Border;

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.To = 0.0;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, border);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Opacity");

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

But when I try to animate the width of the control:

```
private void Item_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = sender as Border;

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.To = 600.0;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, border);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Nothing happens.

I am able to do this in WPF, but not in Windows 8. Is this a limitation or bug of Metro, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have it working in WPF.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetproperty, the target property must be a dependency property.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border, Width is not a dependency property.

Comment: I am able to animate the Width property in WPF and SL, evidenced [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/animation-and-easing/animations-(silverlight-quickstart)#advanced_animations).

Unfortunately this technique doesn't appear to work in WinRT, so you're probably right that Width isn't "animate-able".

Thanks

Comment: @phoog: the documentation you point to actually says that Width is indeed a DependencyProperty, inherited from FrameworkElement, so this is definitely not the reason why this property cannot be animated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width

Comment: Same issue with Line.X1 / Line.X2 etc.. (Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes), work in WPF, not able to make under 8.1.

Comment: @Murven I concluded that Width is not a dependency property because the property page says "This is a dependency property" for several properties, and Width is not one of them.  Apparently I assumed too much of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by enabling `EnableDependentAnimation`

```
    public static async Task Width(FrameworkElement obj, double doubleValue, int milliseconds)
    {
        var animation= new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = doubleValue,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds),
            EnableDependentAnimation = true// <== here
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, obj);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");

        var sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        await sb.BeginAsync();
    }
```

Enjoy!